# jquery drag different shape div and drop to container

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I want to make different shape div draggable and droppable to the container. Also, the different shape which we drop to container also draggable in container area and not overlap each other.

[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/bUcLA/122)

```js
$(".square").draggable({helper: 'clone'});
$(".rect").draggable({helper: 'clone'});

$("#canvas").droppable({
    accept: ".rect, .square",
    drop: function(ev,ui){
        $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(this);
    }
});
```

```css
#canvas {
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.square, .rect {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
    text-align: center;
}

.square {
    background-color: lightyellow;
    width: 80px;
}

.rect {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="square"></div>
<div class="rect"></div>


<div id="canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Please define the behaviour needed more clearly, also please explain the line " should not overlap each other"!

Comment: The `<div>` element will always be a rectangle, it follows the box model. It can be different height and width only.

Comment: Also, you can use `containment` with an array to ensure items cannot be dragged over one another if you like.

Comment: @NarenMurali means different div (different shape) do not overlap each other when we drag

Comment: @Twisty yes I know that but may possible I am used different image instead of div to define different shape

Comment: @Divyesh yes, you can do lots of things like that, even use SVG. But the bounding will always be a box model. Also if you create collision detection, what do you want a dropped item to do? Slide side to side? Move above or below? Revert back to the origin?

Comment: @Divyesh You can use icons to represent other shapes if you want. If `#canvas` is going to be a canvas, then it could draw the shape.

Comment: @Twisty I am not want to used canvas tag. I just put different shape image (100x100) under div (<div><image src='circle.jpg/>')and  make it draggable but when we drag do not overlap shape to each other. If possible please provide any example

Comment: @Divyesh do you want a dragged item to just avoid that area or if it's dropped on that section, do land someplace else. You need to be specific.

Comment: @Twisty there is two section. In section A different shape image(100x100) under div(<div><image src='circle.jpg'/></div>) and make it draggable. Section B is droppable area in which we drag different shape which we define in section A means different shape is drag from section A to section B which is droppable area. But when we drag shapes they don't overlap to eachother in section B.

Comment: @Divyesh I understand that. I am asking about when an item is dragged from A to B, and in B a item already exists, what should happen if the user attempts to drag the item such that it overlaps.

Comment: @Twisty yes user able to dragged any item from A to B if already exists in B  but any item not overlaps eachother

Comment: @Divyesh you're still missing the question. If the user drags the item to B, right over an already existing item, what should happen?

Comment: @Twisty at that time also prevent item to overlaps

Comment: @Divyesh so it sounds like you want the user to be unable to drag the item over any other item at all. Such that the item cannot be dropped on the other items. Is that correct?

Comment: @Twisty yes correct. If possible please provide me working example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171069/discussion-between-divyesh-and-twisty).

Comment: @Twisty Please Open Url [link] (https://ibb.co/kxCxFd) . I want to drop different shape from A to B. and any shape (eg. 101,102,102) draggble in section B But they do not overlap each-other

Comment: @Divyesh found this that may help: https://github.com/dsbaars/jq-ui-draggable-collision

Comment: @Twisty its not working properly...